# How to prevent button from disabling after a click

Tags: jquery

After the alert appears I have x button on it that when clicked on the alert box disappears. I can no longer get the alert to appear again unless I refresh the page. I want to know how to keep the button from disabling and keep it active.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.couponalert').on("click", function(){
        $('#myalert').fadeIn(2000)

    })
});
```

HTML

bootstrap alert

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="myalert" role="alert" align="center" style="font-size:2em">
    <button style="font-size:2em" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
      <strong><u>Available Coupons</u><br> Use this <a href="https://takeoutkit.com?rfsn=1589618.63e1cd&utm_source=refersion&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=1589618.63e1cd">LINK</a> to receive 10 percent off of your first Order from Takeout Kit</strong>
    </div>
```

button

```
<li ><a class="couponalert" href="#">Coupons</a></li>
```

Comment: `$('.couponalert').on("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Can you write the full code please

Answer (score 1):

By default, Bootstrap Alert's close button removes it from the DOM, instead of hiding it. You can override this behaviour by using:

```
$('#myalert button.close').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myalert').fadeOut();
});
```

Do this in the `$(document).ready( ... )` handler, and you will be able to bring it back again.

*Be advised that this will prevent the events `close.bs.alert` and `closed.bs.alert` from firing. If you're not doing much with those events, you're all set.*

Comment: Do you think something might be missing for this code because it didn't work on my end